# React app failed to compile on Heroku - import error?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, import

This is the error what I get when trying to deploy my React app on Heroku:

```
-----> Build
       Running build

       > projectx@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_f8319236f3ff554c9b2b847b7cd7e6f7
       > react-scripts build

       Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.

       ./src/components/application/App.js
       Cannot find file '../landing/Home' in './src/components/application'.
```

I'm not sure why it's searching for my `Home` component in the App.js' local folder (which is `components/application`)

This is a fragment from my App.js. It works fine locally.

```
import DashboardLayout from '../layout/DashboardLayout';
import Home from '../landing/Home';
import Counter from '../dashboard/Counter';
import Login from '../landing/Login';
import Register from '../landing/Register';
    ...
 return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authTokens, setAuthTokens: setTokens }}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <PublicRoute exact path='/' component={Home} layout={LandingLayout} />
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

What am I missing here? Should I use another mode of importing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem, my `landing/` folder was actually `Landing/` in a previous version on Git. Turns out git is not case-sensitive and does not detect folder case-sensitive renames.

So I had to rename the folder in git as well with:

```
git mv Landing/ tmp
git mv tmp/ landing
```